# Gradle publish to Azure Artifacts with Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure, gradle, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-server

I am running gradle publish in Azure Pipelines to publish my artifacts(jar) to Azure Artifactswhich is failing. (Note: We are using Azure Devops Server)
Which is failing with error:

> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Can someone help ?

Comment: This is a confusing error message. The first part is nonsense, but your error is due to not being able to build a certificate path to the host you are attempting to connect to. This means you are likely missing some certificates, either root or intermediate.

Comment: I am still confused, how can I be sure on that this is a certificate issue and not gradle issue?